# Leaderboard not working even though i have looked over many posts

Tags: lua, roblox

My leaderboard

```
function Onplrjoined(plr)

local leaderstats = Instance.new("IntValue")
leaderstats.Parent = plr
leaderstats.Value = 0
leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

local stat = Instance.new("IntValue")
stat.Name = "Coins"
stat.Value = 0
```

end

local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(Onplrjoined)

but when i join in it does not show anything
when i join in it does not show anything

Comment: Ok so i got it working now but how does my code vs another persons code compare?

Comment: Their code:  ``local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

local function createLeaderboard(player)
 local stats = Instance.new("Folder")
 stats.Name = "leaderstats"
 local cash = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
 cash.Name = "Cash"
 stats.Parent = player
end

players.PlayerAdded:connect(createLeaderboard)``

Comment: and my code: ``function Onplrjoined(plr)
 
 local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
 leaderstats.Parent = plr
 leaderstats.Value = 0
 leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
 
 local stat = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
 stat.Name = "Coins"
 stat.Value = 0
 
end

local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(Onplrjoined)``

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the `stat` object in leaderstats

this is easily fixed by this line of code:

```lua
stat.Parent = leaderstats
```

Oh and by the way, use `game:GetService("Players")` instead of `game:WaitForChild("Players")` as this is more clean